# JS - Discord Bot Remove specific ID from array

Tags: javascript, discord

Hello there is the code

```
$bot.on("presenceUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
  if(oldMember.presence.status !== newMember.presence.status){
    const memberID = newMember.user.id;
    if(newMember.user.presence.status === "online"){      
      membersOnline.push(memberID);
      console.log("-------online--------");
      console.log(membersOnline);
    }else
    if(newMember.user.presence.status === "offline"){
      membersOnline.filter(e => e !== memberID)
      console.log("-------offline--------");
      console.log(membersOnline);
    }
      console.log(`${newMember.user.username} is now ${newMember.presence.status}`);

  }
});
```

Resoults is that id not getting removed.

> -------offline-------- []
>
> -l--RACE--l- is now offline
>
> -------online-------- [ '203287818330570752' ]
>
> -l--RACE--l- is now online
>
> -------offline-------- [ '203287818330570752' ]
>
> -l--RACE--l- is now offline
>
> -------online-------- [ '203287818330570752', '203287818330570752' ]
>
> -l--RACE--l- is now online

[DOCS](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Method Array.prototype.filter() not change orginal array. So simple solution is:

```
membersOnline = membersOnline.filter(e => e !== memberID);
```

Comment: membersOnline = membersOnline.filter(e => e !== memberID);
                           ^

TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

Comment: In line where you first declare membersOnline variable change `const membersOnline` to `let membersOnline`

Comment: thank you, that was my mistake... tryed ur solution few hours ago x) now it works with it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the filter method returns an array so in your code you run the method but do not assign the returned value to a variable.  Please see code below...

```
$bot.on("presenceUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if(oldMember.presence.status !== newMember.presence.status){
      const memberID = newMember.user.id;
    }
    if(newMember.user.presence.status === "online"){      
        membersOnline.push(memberID);
        console.log("-------online--------");
        console.log(membersOnline);
    } else {
        if(newMember.user.presence.status === "offline"){
            var newOnlineMembers = membersOnline.filter(e => e !== memberID);  // add new variable for filtered array
            console.log("-------offline--------");
            console.log(newOnlineMembers); // output new variable
        }
        console.log(`${newMember.user.username} is now ${newMember.presence.status}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: this way Iam gonna have 2 arrays, one constantly growing and one without offlines.

Comment: I think you figured it out but you don’t have to create a new array. You can reassign the previous array to what is returned by the filter method.